# My returned average does not look right in terms of decimal places (Python)

Tags: python, string, floating-point

My returned average does not look right in terms of decimal places using +str for a variable.

my code below should provide 25.83 but I get 25.830000000002

```
total_bmi = 0

for bmi in bmis:
  total_bmi += float(bmi)

average_bmi = total_bmi/len(bmis)
print("Average BMI: " + str(average_bmi))
```

Comment: When I got here, there were 5 upvotes on the automatically generated comment proposing a duplicate question. If you think something is a duplicate, and you have the reputation required to cast close votes, please **actually vote to close** duplicates, don't just upvote the "does this answer your question?" comment. Especially if it's a common problem, like here.

Answer (score -1):

The reason for this is how floating point numbers are stored in hardware. Without going into much detail, simply use:

```
total_bmi = 0

for bmi in bmis:
  total_bmi += float(bmi)

average_bmi = total_bmi/len(bmis)
print("Average BMI: " + str(round(average_bmi, 2)))
```

Comment: Don't use `round` for this; use string formatting. That's what it's for. `print(f"Average BMI: {average_bmi:.2f}")`. Or `print("Average BMI: {:.2f}".format(average_bmi))`.